# Extension is not found in phpinfo()

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can see my target php extension installed with phpinfo() in my local PC. 
But in web there is no place I found this extension with phpinfo().

Is there any way to install automatically this extension? I'm using amazon elastic beanstalk web server to deploy my project using Symfony2.

Comment: Which extension ?

Comment: Couchbase Extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need the follow this instructions:

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html

Remember add to your php.ini this to end

extension=couchbase.so

If you have a folder for extension you need to create a new file and added.

exemple:

```
/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/couchbase.ini
```

after on:

```
cd /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/couchbase.ini ./21-couchbase.ini
cd /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d
sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/couchbase.ini ./21-couchbase.ini
```

Restart your webserver and should be work.

But this depends of the web server, In my local apache and PHP I follow that instruction, on our Staging and Prod Machine we are using docker, Nginx and php-fpm can be different.